# How to add effects to UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, effects

I've been searching for that many time ago and I can't find a solution. I have a animated label that crosses the screen of the iPhone (like the title of a song does in the Music [app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gi3xdlvr7nawz0c/musica.jpg).Well, I'd like to add the "fade in/out" effect like the music app has. The easy solution is open Photoshop and create [this simple image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ea9wkfy3fu6xoog/efecte_profunditat%402x.png) and then add it up to the label. Well, under the label I have an image with black backgroud. The image can be zoomed in and then the image with the fade in/out effect can be seen, and it doesn't look well. Is there any possibility to do this programatically? Thanks

PD: if there's another possibility rather than doing this programatically, I'll apreciate the answer as well.

Edit: Here's the [image capture of the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpb924mku12ntgv/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202012-12-27%20a%20les%2010.08.05.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'll approach it in a non-programming way.

The image reference you gave us for the Music app you seem to be emulating has a different gradient than the one you drew in the second image.
If you notice in the image, the gradient has not fully completed its transition from clear to black before the words are cut off. I would say in photoshop run the gradient from clear to 80% alpha black and then draw a 100% alpha black rectangle to finish it off as per [image](http://imageshack.us/a/img42/7519/musicoverlayexample.png). The white is just showing you what it looks like without the black background.

Now as for the zooming. Correct me if I am wrong, but it sounds like you want a viewing window for the image so that once you have zoomed into it, it will fade to either side, but still be viewable/movable in the center.  This means that the image has to be zoom-able, but once you have zoomed the "fade in/out" should *not* be zoom-able.

Just make sure you aren't scaling the fader by keeping it separate from the scrollView of your background image.

Comment: I've updated the question with an image capture of the problem. I don't want to have the effect on the image I have under the label. Your solution looks much better then mine, but I also have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: My less-programming (not no-programming) solution is to have two images, one behind the text that is completely black or whatever color you prefer, and the fader in front of the text. That way the image will not be seen behind the background under the text. This example can be seen in the image in my post. Otherwise, you could do it through coding by changing the viewable area of the picture beneath.